# Observe a change in a boolean array

Tags: ember.js, observers

I have a component that observes an array of items:

```
itemsChanged: Ember.observer('items', 'items.[]', 'items.@each' function () {
    // ...code...
}),
```

This works fine when I have an array of objects with a boolean property.

```
Array(arraySize).fill(false, 0).fill(true, 0, 1).map(model => WrapperBool.create({ model }))
```

However, how can I make it observe when an array of booleans have a value change? The array will always be the same size.

```
Array(arraySize).fill(false, 0).fill(true, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use KVO(KeyValueObservable) compliant methods for modification,
For adding you need to `pushObject` instead of `push` and for a modification you need to use `addObject`, only then corresponding observer will be triggered.

In your case, dependent key `items.[]` is enough. you should not use `items.@each`( I think its deprecated, but I am not sure, anyway you can use `items.[]` it will care of addition/deletion of items).

application.js,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({  
  items:[true,false],
  itemsChanged:Ember.observer('items.[]',function(){
    console.log(' items ',this.get('items'));
  }),
  actions:{
    test(){      
      this.get('items').addObject(true);
    }
  }
});
```

application.hbs

```
<h1{{action 'test'}}>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
{{items}}
```

[sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e3d9b68b3aa616abbda687490ec874bd?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) for playing

Comment: I'm not adding or deleting items. It's a fixed size array. The only thing I'm doing is changing the bool values.

Comment: so you should use like this `this.get('items').replace(1,1,[true]);`  , it will trigger the observer, if you dont want to do it like this, then there is `notifyPropertyChange` method which you can call, this will notify all the oberserver to fire..[Modifed twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e3d9b68b3aa616abbda687490ec874bd?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)